# No Display Signal whatsoever after switching graphics driver

Tags: boot, 22.04, reboot, recovery-mode

Ubuntu 22.04 Primary
Windows 10 Dual Boot
AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
ASRock B550M-C
RTX 3070

I recently tried to get my RTX 3070 working on the linux half of my dual boot system. I'm a complete noob at this sort of thing. After switching from X.orgX server to NVIDIA driver (open kernel) 525 and restarting, my PC would not provide any HDMI signal to any ports on my graphics card or the motherboard.

I tried restarting several times. I tried some key binds I found online to try and open recovery mode or GRUB, even the BIOS so that I could switch to my windows version which I know to be working, but no matter what I did all I could see was that there was no HDMI signal. Finally, I reset the CMOS bios hoping that I could see the bios, but, again, nothing but a black screen and fans.

Prior to this I had several months of flawless dual boot operation, with no indication that anything was working less than perfectly except every so often Ubuntu would crash.

When I power on the red lights on my motherboard blink in a normal pattern. After this brief startup phase those lights are off. My hard drive light on my case is a solid blue with intermittent blinking red.

This is really scary and I don't know what to do. I can't even get into my windows OS because I cant get the PC to display BIOS. I could be doing it wrong, because I'm not an expert at this sort of thing.

Please help me. I need this PC to be working for me to to my school work.

Comment: Except for a hardware issue, the only remaining possible software issue is that your computer is booting so quickly into the Ubuntu partition that even accessing the BIOS is impossible unless you temporarily disconnect the cable to the hard drive that Ubuntu is installed on. Then you can boot the Ubuntu installer USB, access the BIOS, put the Ubuntu USB first in the BIOS boot sequence, and reinstall Ubuntu. If you have any questions just ask. Please let me know if this suggestion worked. This is not an uncommon problem and the Ubuntu community deserves to know how it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

After being shut off and unplugged for several hours, I got a newer HDMI cable and tried that and everything worked. The new drivers seem to be working fine with no issues.